# How to detect the USB printer port in the tablet and print the document

Tags: android

I have made an application which reads the pdf files, i want to print the document from the tablet. so when i connect the printer's USB to the port it should first detect the USB is connected or not and then if printer is connected print the document.if anyone has the idea for this concept please share here.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: which android version you are planning to use ?

Comment: I think it is not going to support, because Android introduce UsbManager in the version 4.0.

Comment: no it supports 3.0 or upper version

Comment: ok, yes [Usb Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html) is available in API 12 Android 3.1

Comment: so is there any way to what i want to do.

Comment: sorry, but not yet work that much at present, but surely will do in near future, i have same kind of requirement.

Comment: @Lucifer: if u find any source related to this requirement.please let me know

Comment: I also need this type of code..so please help me out as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lucifer, u r genius, please help me to complete my app that has functionality to connect printer with wifi.

Comment: Lucifer please help me .........................